# Laravel Controller does not exist after site move. Works on Vagrant/Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, laravel-5

I am working on a Laravel site. I have been working locally with Homestead / Vagrant and the site works fine. I just moved the site to: http://goferapp.io

On the new live site (still in development) I am getting the following error screen:

[image]

I have made sure in my controller to use the right namespace:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Landlord;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Session;
use Sentinel;
use App\Property;
use App\Tenant;
use App\WaitingList;
use App\ServiceRequest;
use App\Document;
use App\User;
use Mail;
use Carbon;

class LandlordController extends Controller...
```

In my routes file I have:

```
Route::get('/dashboard', ['middleware' => 'postlog', 'uses' => 'LandLord\LandlordController@index']);
```

Here's my folder structure:

[image]

I cannot figure out why it works perfectly in my local environment and wont work live. I've cleared the cache with a special function:

```
Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
        $exitCode = Artisan::call('cache:clear');
        return 'cache cleared!';
    });
```

I'm at a loss now how to get this working. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you run a `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Check the permissions on the file itself and the containing folder.

Comment: I'm not sure if Laravel is this case-sensitive or not, but I did notice that in the error message the path is `Controllers/LandLord` and in the file structure it's `Controllers/Landlord`.

Comment: i've run composer dump-autoload and i've checked permissions. No go on either. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem should be with the folder/file names. In the Routes you have

```
  Route::get('/dashboard', ['middleware' => 'postlog', 'uses' => 'LandLord\LandlordController@index']);
```

see the `uses`

```
'uses' => 'LandLord\LandlordController@index']);
```

Change it to

```
 'uses' => 'Landlord\LandlordController@index']);
```

ie, `LandLord` to `Landlord`. Some servers are not that forgiving. :-)

also, run `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Yep that was it. Thanks for the help.